# Сделать заглавными последние буквы каждого слова

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Надо сделать заглавными последние буквы каждого слова.
   Но CodeHunt не считает мой код самым коротким. Как сделать еще короче?

```
public class Program {

    public static String Puzzle(String s) {
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        {
            if (i==chars.length-1 || chars[i+1]==' ')
                chars[i]=Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
        }

        return new String(chars);
    }
}
```

Входные данные Выходные данные

```
"i      "       "I      "

"aaaaaa"        "aaaaaA"        

" bbhbh"        " bbhbH"
```

Comment: Можно java 8 использовать?

Comment: Не знаю, попробуйте.

Comment: CodeHunt количество строк кода смотрит или как?

Comment: Наверное, сравнивает с эталонным.

Comment: Код-гольф? _(5 символов нужно...)_

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос примеры входных данных. В предложениях могут быть знаки препинания, переносы строки, множественные пробелы, другие пробельные символы, цифры, слова с цифрами, слова разделенные чем-то кроме пробела (`Мамин-Сибиряк`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
char[] с = (s + " ").toCharArray();
for (int i = 1; i < с.length; i++)
    if (с[i]==' ') 
        с[i-1]=Character.toUpperCase(с[i-1]);
return new String(с);
```

**Update**:

В условии выше не учитываются знаки препинания как разделители слов, то есть фраза "Вася,Петя,Сережа" будет одним словом, так как такие тестовые задания часто принимают пробел как единственные разделитель. Но если нужно учитывать знаки препинания, то используйте этот код (он будет считать разделителями все кроме букв и цифр):

```
char[] с = (s + " ").toCharArray();
for (int i = 1; i < с.length; i++)
    if ( !Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) ) 
        с[i-1]=Character.toUpperCase(с[i-1]);
return new String(с);
```

Comment: Последний символ обрабатывается. if (i==s.length()-1 условие есть.

Comment: А у вас обрабатывается?

Comment: поправил, обновил ответ

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin А что если пользователь забыл поставить пробел после запятую или точку?

Comment: @Grolisc если запятая и после пробел — этот код попытается сделать `.toUpperCase(',')`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Выходит и с запятой, точкой с пробелом тоже не сработает

Comment: А тут вопрос чем является разделитель, в таких учебных заданиях часто это не учитывается и считается что слова делятся только пробелами, если нужно сложнее можно заменить строчку if (с[i]==' ') на if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))

Comment: В результате таки остаётся лишний пробел =) И даже после фикса codehunt даёт один кирпич из трёх..

Comment: Запятых не надо учитывать. Главное, короткий код

Answer (score 5):

Как-то так:

```
private static String lastToUpperCase(String text) {
    String res = "";
    for (String s : text.split("\\b"))
        if (s.length() == 1) res += s.toUpperCase();
        else res += s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)
                + s.substring(s.length() - 1).toUpperCase();
    return res;
}
```

Input: I want to walk my dog.
Печатает: I wanT tO walK mY doG.

Comment: Выдает ошибку при вводе "     a"

Comment: Если в строке в конце несколько пробелов

Comment: Я подбираю слова регуляркой, и поэтому сколько бы там не было пробелов мой код их не считает. Я тоже попробовал с " a" конце. Все отлично работает. Какую ошибку выдает у Вас.

Comment: @Fonnadema, там версия java какая-то древняя, видимо. `String.substring(0, 0)` бросает ошибку.

Comment: "ai i  "  "aI I  "

Comment: Пробуйте на входных данных с пробелами в конце

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, вы можете написать `if (s.length() == 1){res+=s.toUpperCase();} else { res +=...}`, всё будет работать, но на один кирпич)

Comment: Напоминаю, что нужен работающий код, но короче моего.

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо. Видимо вы правы там старая Java стоит наверное, исправил.

Answer (score 2):

используя

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;
```

получается:

```
String inputString = "this string is needed to be last letter-uppercased for each word";
String outputString = StringUtils.reverse(WordUtils.capitalize(StringUtils.reverse(inputString)));

// System.out.println(outputString):
// thiS strinG iS needeD tO bE lasT letter-uppercaseD foR eacH worD
```

---

<sub>подглядел: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42302143/6104996</sub>

Comment: Увы, не позволяет использовать эту библиотеку.